# Failed to create producer binding

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

> Kafka producer binding issue 2019-01-04 03:58:18.497 ERROR
>   [api-gateway-server,,,] 1 --- [ask-scheduler-1]
>   o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService : Failed to create producer
>   binding; retrying in 30 seconds
>   headless_api-gateway-service.1.w48xs2v2sfjl@node8.docker.com |
>   headless_api-gateway-service.1.w48xs2v2sfjl@node8.docker.com |
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException:
>   provisioning exception; nested exception is
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        outboundThrottling:
          destination: throttlingTopic_Headless
          content-type: application/json
          compression-type: gzip
        outboundBre1:
          destination: Topic_Bre1_Headless
          content-type: application/json
          compression-type: gzip
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${broker}
          zk-nodes: ${broker}
  profiles:
    active: default
```

It is able to connect to cluster but not able to make producer binding hence not able to stream the event

Comment: First, please do not double post - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/527#issuecomment-451349284. . . not necessary. As I replied in GH, there is not enough information provided. It could be networking issue, security, doker configuration etc.. . . but as I said these are all speculations and without a reproducible sample they will remain as such.